# NGINX Reverse Proxy that encrypts all Data for Nextcloud

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I have a Nextcloud (Port 8080) Docker Container running and I want to encrypt the datastream with ssl.

So I found out that I can do things like that with nginx (reverse Proxy with SSL), but I couldn't find a way how...

I already have a Key and Private Key Certificate on my pi generated by lets encrypt lying around, so basically if you connect to my Domain with http/80 it should redirect the data to the proxy and the proxy should "proxy" all data through to `localhost:8080`.

And I should add, yes, I tried the official way for this (with the nginx reverse proxy docker and the lets encrypt companion) but it doesn't work bc I'm doing it on a pi (arm).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use a popular Nginx container by the awesome Linuxserver guys, named "Swag" (it does have an ARM version as well).

https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/swag

They even have a [pre-configured Nextcloud proxy config](https://github.com/linuxserver/reverse-proxy-confs/blob/master/nextcloud.subdomain.conf.sample) setup for you, all you have to do is rename the file, removing `.sample` from the end of it.